# Should sauerkraut on hot dogs be washed

Tags: sauerkraut, hot-dog

I'm a recent convert to the fermented cabbage dish Sauerkraut which I know is popular in Germany and Poland.  On TV I've seen this served on hot dogs in The States and was wondering whether it is traditionally washed to produce a milder flavour before being used?

Comment: No, saurkraut is not traditionally washed, but there are an infinite number of hot dog eating traditions.  I am not sure that there is any single answer to what else goes with saurkraut on a hot dog.

Comment: I add mustard, even though both *Sauerkraut/zuurkool* and mustard are already sour.

Comment: American Sauerkraut is milder tasting not because it's washed, but because it is pasteurized to extend shelf life, which kills the live cultures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really comes down to taste. In this usage, you're treating sauerkraut like a condiment so there's not really a "correct" answer.. A lot of hot dog places have traditions - for instance, Nathan's Famous hot dogs (the original "Coney Island" hot dog) uses these combinations with kraut:

-Sauerkraut, spicey brown mustard (New York style)
-Thousand island dressing, sauerkraut, swiss cheese (Reuben style)

A famous hot dog maker in Pennsylvania, Yocco's Famous Dogs, uses sauerkraut and a thin bean chili combination to make their hot dogs.

The sauerkraut will often be very strong tasting, but not as "funky" as kimchi. It pairs well with a lot of different foods, usually other strong flavors (either strong tart like the spicey mustard, or strong sweet like the thousand island dressing or sweet relish).

Personally, I just eat sauerkraut with a fork. But if I have it on a dog, I pile it on with dill relish, country style dijon mustard, a dash of sriracha, and some diced onion. I recommend not kissing anyone for awhile after eating.

Comment: Thanks for the information, some interesting suggestions to try!